# How to programmatically scroll TreeView control?

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, scroll

Please advice how can I scroll a .NET TreeView Control programmatically.

It doesn't implemented any public methods to scrolling.

Comment: Which UI framework? Windows Forms, ASP.NET, WPF, or Silverlight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to scroll to the node:

```
TreeNode.EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: yup, if you know exactly what node you are looking for then the above peice of code will programmatically scroll to the node in question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
treeView1.TopNode = treeView1.Nodes[500];
```

---

**EDIT**
Maybe more suggestive :-)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(i.ToString());
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                node.Nodes.Add(j.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void ScrollNode(TreeNode node) {
        treeView1.TopNode = node;
        treeView1.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        if (node.IsExpanded) {
            foreach (TreeNode subNode in node.Nodes)
                ScrollNode(subNode);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Focus();
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes) {
            ScrollNode(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if there isn't 500 nodes?!

Comment: What if you don't have 500 nodes? ;-)

Comment: Florian, thanks for the answer. How can I attach the external VScrollBar to TreeView?

Comment: Sorry to all for the sloppy answer! @Murat: I changed my example.

Comment: Florian, many thanks for your time and for the sample. But how can I sync a VScrollBarControl on a Form and TreeView control?

So I can scroll TreeView by my Custom VScrollBar control.

Answer (score 0):

Just select and unselect the lowest item. That should do the trick.